# Vaadin the view change, forget the information

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I wanted to save the information, during the view change.
When I go from one view to another view, I Be Lost the load information of the opposite view.
How can i keep the information or how can i keep the view

I use in my application that source code
http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=java_learn-master/vd7_learn/src/main/java/com/mycompany/MyVaadinUI.java

Thank you in advance

Comment: What information do you want to track when switching views? What is your intention?

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, you provide View for navigator as class, so it creates new instance of class on each navigation.
You should use addView with instance of your class.
Example:

```
getNavigator().addView("page1", new PageView());
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to save the information in the VaadinSession.

In view1, do this:

```
UI.getCurrent().getSession().setAttribute("param_name", "param_value");
```

In view 2, do this:

```
String param_value = UI.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute("param_name");
```

`param_value` could be instance of any class.